# Game Maker Language: place_meeting doesn't seem to work

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'm making a Pac-Man-like game and I wanted to recreate the Pac-Man maze, but I wanted to make it easier for myself, so that when I change the wall placement it would automatically change the way the wall looks. My pac-man sprite as well as my wall sprites are 16px*16px. Here are the wall sprite images: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clOkb.png) . Here is the room inside the room editor: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv7xj.png) . And here is how it looks in-game: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gU2M.png) .
Here is my code inside the create event of obj_wall:

```
image_speed = 0;

//see where we have blocks
up = place_meeting(x, y - 16, obj_wall);
upright = place_meeting(x + 16, y - 16, obj_wall);
right = place_meeting(x + 16, y, obj_wall);
downright = place_meeting(x + 16, y + 16, obj_wall);
down = place_meeting(x, y + 16, obj_wall);
downleft = place_meeting(x - 16, y + 16, obj_wall);
left = place_meeting(x - 16, y, obj_wall);
upleft = place_meeting(x - 16, y - 16, obj_wall);

//determine how should the wall look
if(up && upright && right && downright && down && downleft && left && upleft)
{
    image_index = 3;
}
if( (down && up && !left) || (down && up && !right) )
{
    image_index = 1;
}
if( (right && left && !up) || (right && left && !down) )
{
    image_index = 1;
    image_angle = 90;
}
if( (right && down && !downright) || (right && down && !upleft && !left && !up) )
{
    image_index = 2;
}
if( (up && left && !upleft) || (up && left && !downright && !right && !down) )
{
    image_index = 2;
    image_yscale = -1;
    image_xscale = -1;
}
if( (up && right && !upright) || (up && right && !downleft && !left && !down) )
{
    image_index = 2;
    image_yscale = -1;
}
if( (down && left && !downleft) || (down && left && !upright && !up && !right) )
{
    image_index = 2;
    image_xscale = -1;
}
```

I'm using Game Maker Studio 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I solved it. Since in the third 'if' I change the image_angle I should undo it in all other 'if's